# A problem concerning a partially ordered in $\omega$ and two chains.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Assume that $P=\left\langle\omega, \preceq\right\rangle$ is a partially ordered set such that for each $n \in \omega$ there are two chains $A_n$ an $B_n$ in $P$ such that $n \subset A_n \cup B_n$. Prove that there are two chains $A$ an $B$ in $P$ such that $\omega=A \cup B$.

$\star$ $\star$ Looking for advice on how to begin approaching this problem.

I am pretty sure that Zorn's lemma will play a role but I don't even know how to begin...

Comment: This looks like the sort of problem that is addressed by Konig's lemma. Have you looked at that?

Comment: @Carl. I have only really seen Konig's lemma applied to graphs. I am not sure how to apply it here.

Comment: In that case, this problem will be educational! There are many things like this that can be proved with Konig's lemma.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hint. Konig's lemma says that every finitely branching infinite tree has an infinite path. What if we make a subtree of $2^{<\omega}$ so that any path through the tree is a partition of $\omega$ into two chains of the partial order $P$?

Comment: How should I interpret $2^{< \omega}$?

Comment: $2^{< \omega}$ is the set of all finite sequences of 0s and 1s.